# Is AES reducible to an NP-complete problem?

Tags: aes

Is breaking AES NP-hard?  Can the security of AES be reduced to a NP-complete problem?

If it is reducible, what does the reduction look like?
If it is not reducible, why do we assume it is secure?

Comment: We know no such reductions for any cryptosystem we use in practice. Not AES, nor RSA. Such reduction isn't too useful in the first place, since complexity classes talk about asymptotic cost, whereas we want to know if a certain concrete key-size is secure.

Comment: How does it "seems clear"? It is clear that some problems relating to some attacks lie in NP (assuming some kind of generalization which allows growing key sizes, simply guessing the right key and then verifying them solves it – the same goes for secret-key crypto), I don't see how you get that they are NP-hard.

Comment: I thought that PKC is NP-hard because its security relies on the difficulty of factoring large integers.

Comment: The question is motivated by the fact that I've heard it mentioned multiple times that all of our modern-day cryptography would be instantly broken if P = NP, and someone demonstrated an algorithm for solving NP problems in polynomial time.

Comment: "Being broken when $P = NP$" doesn't mean "being unbroken when $P \neq NP$". RSA is broken when factoring is easy, but neither is factoring known to be NP-complete nor is it known that RSA can only be broken by factoring the modulus (this is just the best known way nowadays). It is similar for most other public-key algorithms. (And even less for symmetric "bit-shuffling" crypto.)

Comment: It is known that for most "bit-shuffling" cryptographic tasks, the existence of a secure scheme to do it is equivalent to the existence of one-way functions. $\:$

Comment: Actually, it's not at all true that someone showing $P=NP$ implies that all cryptography is broken.  For one, an existence proof (that is, a proof that $P=NP$ that does not give an explicit reduction) doesn't affect the practical security at all.  In addition, an explicit reduction of an NP-hard problem of size $n$ that takes either $2^{1000} n$ or $n^{1000}$ operations would suffice to show $P=NP$, but would be of no practical concern.  To be of concern, we would have to show that large NP-hard problems can be practically solved.

Comment: In addition, neither the factoring of large integers, nor the RSA problem (which is, as far as we know, distinct) are known to be NP-hard.  In fact, it would appear to be unlikely; if they were NP-hard, that would imply that all NP problems can be solved in subexponential time.  That is certainly possible, however that would be rather surprising.

Comment: @CodesInChaos why not make that first remark an answer?

Answer (score 4):

There are some complexity-theoretic reasons to believe that cryptography *can't* be based on NP-completeness. For one example, see [this paper by Akavia et al](http://people.csail.mit.edu/akavia/AGGM.pdf). Basically it all boils down to the mismatch between average-case hardness required for cryptography, and worst-case hardness required for NP-hardness. Moreover, many (most? all?) hard algebraic problems which serve as the basis for cryptography are in NP $\cap$ co-NP (for one such example, consider factoring). Such problems cannot be NP-complete unless NP = co-NP. You can see more discussion in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311064/are-there-public-key-cryptography-algorithms-that-are-provably-np-hard-to-defeat).

Finally, AES is a finite-domain function. It is invertible / distinguishable from a random permutation in (large but) constant time. The definitions of P, NP, etc., refer to asymptotic behavior -- that is, as the input size grows to infinity. Because of the algebraic structure of AES, it is probably possible to define a "generalized AES" for infinitely many key lengths (though there are many semi-arbitrary choices to be made). We could then ask about the asymptotic behavior of such a generalized AES. I'm not sure if anyone has done so.